# Get images from XML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, mod-perl

I would like to get images from XML file below.

Part of how to get images url from XML file below but I can not receive it:

```
my @imageurl;     
foreach my $img(@{$_->{images}}){     
my $imgurl = &makeScalar($img->{image}->[0]);
```

I think something is wrong here: `my $imgurl = &makeScalar($img->{image}->[0]);` 
because if do this:

```
my @imageurl;     
foreach my $img(@{$_->{images}}){     
my $imgurl = &makeScalar($img->{image_0}->[0]);
```

I get only one image instead of 3 images?

### XML file where images are:

```
<images>
    <image_0>url of image 1</image_0>
    <image_1>ulr of image 2</image_1>
    <image_2>url of image 3</image_2>
 </images>
```

### Complete code:

```
package test::test1_123;
use strict;
use warnings;
use onb;
use base qw/;
use URI::URL;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
#use Unicode::String qw(utf8 latin1 utf16be);
use constant TASK_ID => 2084;
use constant CR_TYPE => '2084';
use constant IMAGE_PATH => "/home/public_html/files/";#"images/";

sub new
{
    #Initialization
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new(CR_TYPE, TASK_ID);
    bless $self, $class;
    #Initialization ends

    my $url = 'http://www.url.com.asp?id=18&show=1000&page=1';


    my $xml = $self->geturl('url'=>$url);
    $self->extract($xml);


        #$self->teardown;
}

sub extract{
my $self = shift;
my $xmlfile = shift;
my $xml = new XML::Simple(ForceArray=>1,'KeyAttr' =>'image');
my $data = $xml->XMLin($xmlfile);


PASS:foreach(@{$data->{property}}){    

      my $property = &makeScalar($_->{id}->[0]);    

# get images from XML
      my @imageurl;   
      foreach my $img(@{$_->{images}}){
    my $imgurl = &makeScalar($img->{image_0}->[0]);

      push @imageurl,$imgurl;
      }
}
        my $detail = {};

          $detail->{cr_type}  = CR_TYPE;
          $detail->{catid}    = '434';
          $detail->{userid}   = '2084'; 
          $detail->{hw_added}   = &get_date;
          $detail->{hw_updated} = &get_date;

            unless ($self->exists_item($detail->{site_id}))
        {
            my $insertid = $self->add(%{$detail});

     #get last insert id and update images

     #get images and save them into a folder
            my $count = 0;
            my $imgstr;
            foreach my $u(@imageurl){
               my $res = $self->geturl('url'=>$u);
               my $filename = IMAGE_PATH . "item_" . $insertid;
                  $filename = $filename . '_' . $count if $count > 0;
                  $filename = $filename . ".jpg";
                              $imgstr = $imgstr . "" . "item_" . $insertid .".jpg" if $count == 0;
                  $imgstr = $imgstr . "\n" . "item_" . $insertid . "_" . $count .".jpg" if $count > 0;
                  $count++;
                  open FILE,">$filename";binmode(FILE);print FILE $res;close FILE;
                  &ResizeImg($filename,100,100) if -e $filename;

            }

            my $imgs ={};
               $imgs->{link_id} = $insertid;
               $imgs->{images}  = $imgstr;
            $self->update_img(%{$imgs});

        }
}
}



sub get_date {
    my ($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $mon, $year, $dweek, $dyear, $daylight) = localtime(time());
    my (@months) = qw!Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec!;
    ($day < 10) and ($day = "0$day");
    $year = $year + 1900;
    $mon = $mon +1;
     return "$year-$mon-$day $hour-$min-$sec";

}
sub makeScalar() {
    if ($_[0]=~/HASH\(0x(\d|\w)+\)/) { return ''; }
    return $_[0];
}
sub ResizeImg
{
   my ($file,$width_max,$height_max) = @_;
   eval { require GD; };
   return if $@;
   my $image = GD::Image->new($file);
   return unless $image;
   my ($width,$height) = $image->getBounds();
   my ($dx,$dy)=(0,0);
   if($width/$height >= $width_max/$height_max) ### Horizontal
   {
      $dx = sprintf("%.0f", ($width-$width_max*$height/$height_max)/2 );
   }
   else
   {
      $dy = sprintf("%.0f", ($height-$height_max*$width/$width_max)/2 );
   }
   my $thumb = GD::Image->newTrueColor($width_max,$height_max);
   $thumb->copyResampled($image,0,0,$dx,$dy,$width_max,$height_max,$width-2*$dx,$height-2*$dy);

   my $jpegdata = $thumb->jpeg(70);
   $file=~s/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$//i;
   $file=~s/\/files\//\/files\/small\//i;
   open(FILE,">$file.jpg")||warn "can't write th:$!";
   binmode FILE;
   print FILE $jpegdata;
   close(FILE);
}

1;
```

Comment: trim your full code down to a short, runnable example, including the part that actually parses the xml

Comment: alternatively, show output of `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $_;` just before the foreach loop.

Comment: I assume you are using `XML::Simple`? Please show your complete XML and code.

Comment: I just post complte code. Please look above.

Comment: Oh, this code is so full of WTFs (seriously, `sprintf "%.0f"` instead of `int`?). At least it used `strict` ;-) However, it won't compile: (1) I have no idea what the `onb` module is, (2) The `qw//` list for `use base` isn't terminated. As you refer to an inherited method in your constructor, the superclass is *relevant*.

Comment: @amon: `sprintf "%.0f", $float` is an idiom for rounding to the nearest integer. `int` does a `floor`.

Comment: a problem is just in this part of code: # get images from XML
      my @imageurl;   
      foreach my $img(@{$_->{images}}){
    my $imgurl = &makeScalar($img->{image_0}->[0]);

Comment: worse wtf, setting an empty prototype on `makeScalar` then defeating it with `&makeScalar(...)`. WHY?

Comment: @JoelBerger That non-prototype is among the best things about `makeScalar`. The real fun is stringifying a reference, then testing for the type with a regex which even uses a capture group as a charclass. (should be `return ref $_[0] eq 'HASH' ? "" : $_[0]` instead). The not quite consistent naming conventions for the subs aren't bad either (`get_date`, `makeScalar` and `ResizeImg`).

Comment: @amon, you know, I couldn't even bring myself to read that far! Yeah, that's bad too!

Answer (score 3):

First of all *XML::Simple is a deprecated module* that you should avoid if at all possible, precisely for the reason you see here: that it is often very difficult to predict and process the Perl data structure that it produces. The module documentation itself says this

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are
>       available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.
>       In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options and
>       the arbitrary ways in which these options interact - often with
>       unexpected results.

So if at all possible I suggest that you migrate to [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) or 
[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig).

As it stands I can see no reason why your code doesn't work, and if you won't show your XML then no one can help. It looks to me like, with the `XML::Simple` options you have in place, each element of `@{$data->{property}}` should look like this.

```
{
  id => [99],
  images => [
    {
      image_0 => ["url of image 1"],
      image_1 => ["url of image 2"],
      image_2 => ["url of image 3"],
    },
  ],
}
```

So `for my $img (@{$_->{images}}) { ... }` is looping over a single-element array that looks like

```
[
  {
    image_0 => ["url of image 1"],
    image_1 => ["url of image 2"],
    image_2 => ["url of image 3"],
  },
]
```

and `$img->{image_0}[0]` should be the string `url of image 1`.

Show your data and your *real* program and we will be able to help you further.

Comment: Yes, this($img->{image_0}->[0] ) works to get just one image. But how to get all images $img->{image_0}->[0], $img->{image_1}->[0], $img->{image_2}->[0], $img->{image_n}->[0]?